# Current source circuit components

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, constant-current

I want to make a constant current driver for a laser diode (500 mA max.) based on the circuit shown below:

[image]

Here is my version:

[image]

In my case D2 and D3 represent the laser diode. There is a NC relay and D4 is protecting the relay. The relay is there to short the laser pins when not used for ESD protection. D1 is for reverse polarity protection.

I want to use another op-amp ([OP284](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/op184_284_484.pdf)) and transistor ([TIP120](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf)). Thd left side of the circuit is providing a soft start to the op-amp's input.

In such circuits they use a feedback resistor and capacitor, but in the first circuit there aren't any.

[image]

Also in the [first circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaBZ3.png) there is a parallel RC with the laser diode where in my case I made it 10 kΩ and 100 nF. There is an 8 μF capacitor at the transistor base which I don't see in many other examples.

My questions are:

1. Regarding [my schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUscJ.png), my op-amp is specced as unity-gain stable. Do I need a feedback resistor and capacitor (C5 and R10)? And how can I estimate their values?
2. What are the R and C parallel to the laser diode used for (R8 and C6 in my schematic)?
3. What could be the reason for the capacitor at the transistor's base (C7 in my schematic)?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend the feedback capacitor (C5). I might place it in parallel with R10, but it is probably OK where it is. It performs the same function as C7, which you should remove from your design; it provides a filter for noise on the reference input from the power supply. As far as recommending values for R10 and C7, I would simulate the circuit and introduce whatever noise source you expect on your -5 V supply in the simulation. R10 is usually matched to the impedance seen at the op amp's "+" input (around 4k), but this value is not critical in this design.
2. R8 and C6 perform two functions. When the circuit is first turned on, the voltage across R8 will rise slowly as C6 is charged. Similarly, when power is removed, C6 will discharge slowly. This will guard against any nonlinear response from U2 during power-up and power down.
3. The original circuit uses an extremely old op amp, capable only of frequency response in the 10-20 kHz range. You should not use an 8 uF capacitor as you have shown with a modern op amp. C7 will not be required in your case, because your op amp has higher frequency response.

Another note: 500 mA is only going to produce 300 mV across R7. You can see from the data sheet that the frequency performance is guaranteed from 0.5 to 4.5 V, so I would use a sense resistor (R7 in your schematic) of about 1.2 Ω.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. You didn't comment on feedback resistor and capacitor C5 values for OP284 case? And why they are needed. Or are they needed at all? Secondly is the data sheet's frequency performance for the opmap still relevant in my case?(where I wont modulate the laser current just set it to a fixed current and leave it)

Comment: I edited may answer to show C5 as the "feedback" capacitor.  As far as values, you may want to simulate as I said to handle noise you have on you supply; a larger capacitor and resistor mean slower start-up but act as a better filter.  It's counter-intuitive for some, but the high-frequency response of an op amp is important for low-pas filtering.  The op amp's negative feedback contains the high frequencies and must be able to amplify them to cancel them out.  So absolutely you need the feedback capacitor.